# Automator choose finder folder and run shell script

Tags: automator, script, command-line

I've got a simple shell script that I would like to incorporate into an automator workflow. I just need to double click the application , pick a finder folder and run the command. At the moment it is running in my default user directory. I've found how to do this as a service, but I'd like it to work as an application.
How can I get to run in the chosen folder? Optionally a drag and drop onto the application would be nice as well.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply pass the selected folder to the shell script by selecting "as argument" from the "pass input:" dropdown-menu and then adding `"$@"` at the point in your script where you want the folder path to be used.

To use drag&drop, just remove the "ask for finder items" action and let the "run shell script" receive the input from "application can receive files and folders as input".

Comment: I've seen the "$@" command but wasn't sure how to use it. I simply put "cd $@" at the beginning of my script and it solved the problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Actually, I'd recommend using `cd "$1"` instead.  `$@` expands to the list of all arguments passed to the script, and if there's more than one `cd` will just gripe that it can't go more than one place; `$1` expands to the first argument, so if you manage to pass it more than one it'll just go with the first.  Also, make sure you use double-quotes around it, to keep the shell from getting confused by funny characters (like spaces) in the folder path.

Comment: @Gordon In this case, with the "Allow Multiple Selection" checkbox unchecked, there will actually never be more than one argument passed to the shell script. Putting $@ in double quotes is indeed necessary (as I did in my original answer).

Answer (score -1):

The way I do this is define the path to a variable, then open up the workflow in a text editor, search for the variable, copy the string, then use $(string) anywhere in the workflow whatsoever (including shell scripts).